# Can I create this shape with the pseudo elements :before and :after?

Tags: css

I want to create this shape just with css.
Can I do it with the pseudo elements :before and :after?
[image]

Comment: Yes you can. I would have the thin bar be the main element, then the left shape :before and the right shape :after.

Comment: Why is JavaScript tagged? This is a VERY broad question that you have given no attempt to solve. It will likely be closed.

Comment: yes, you can. (ironic reply to non-specific question)

Comment: Yes you can. But would involve `skewing/transforming` elements, and `overflow:hidden`, z-index etc, so it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the [clip](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) property.

```
.yourClass:after {
background: #ccc;
clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

or

```
.yourClass:before {
background: #ccc;
clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

You will also need to use the transition property as well to rotate your clip. You will need to break this up between a few divs.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like [this](http://codepen.io/GuiHarrison/pen/fpsnA) you imagined?

I used the `transform:skew` property to make it work.

Comment: That works.. But the problem is what happends when you put text in there. It will skew also. There are ways around that.. Excellent JOB! +1

Comment: Indeed, some workarounds are needed to fit this in a real project. Good to clarify.

Comment: I tried using skew but it messed up my text. The question is, is the person using this only for graphical purpose or for an actual navbar of some sort.